# Can I reactivate a CD-key on a new account if the old account was deleted?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

Can I use the CD-key again in the new steam account if the old account in which the cd-key is used is deleted? can cd-key will be valid?

Comment: What do you mean by deleted? AFAIK it's not possible to delete a Steam account.

Comment: @TZHX - At least not by a button on the UI- there's a couple of ways an account can be deleted: If Steam knows the account is a scam/spam account it'll be removed, plus I'm sure it's possible to email Valve to remove your account manually as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can't activate the same key twice. If you could use the same key on multiple accounts there would be no reason to buy it. Once activated through steam key can never be re-used again seeing the key is tied to account.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Once activated, the game is tied to that account, and the CD-Key becomes useless. You will have to re-purchase the game for the new account.

Alternatively, if you've simply lost the password/email to your account you could contact [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com) and attempt to recover your original account.